# Problems configuring TeXMaker to use XeTeX

Tags: texmaker

I tried to use user command "xelatex %" or change quick build to "User" with "xelatex %", but neither one gives any output when executed. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Try to run it "by hand" to see what output do you get. Open the Terminal for Linux/Mac OS X or Command Prompt in Windows and then run:

```
xelatex <name>.tex
```

I also tested it with "Options-> Configure TeXmaker" and changing the `latex` command to `xelatex`. When I now run it with the coice `latex` it works.
[image]

Comment: It's fine. And such user command can be run without problem under TeXMakerX (but I don't like the X version).

Comment: @Karus: see ma edited answer. I just tested it whith changing the latex command

Comment: It didn't work. Guess it has something to do with my system.

Comment: @Karsus: On my OS X with TexmakerX I have to give the full path to a command: `"/usr/texbin/xelatex" %.tex` instead of `xelatex %.tex`

Comment: @Karsus: do you have a `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/.../:$PATH` in your local config setting? This is needed for TeXLive from http://tug.org/texlive

Comment: @Herbert: I'm using Windows, and TeXLive 2011 is in the path (otherwise pdflatex wouldn't work either). Full path didn't work

Answer (score 0):

To solve the proble in my system, I had to manually add the path of *TeX commands under "Add to PATH".

To be more exact, since I am using MacPorts, I aded the following entry and everything works as expected:

```
/opt/local/bin/
```